# Why is my computer suddenly very laggy after a recent reboot?

Tags: windows-7, performance

My computer worked perfectly fine until a recent reboot. I normally reboot every week or so. But this time, the computer feels very laggy.

By laggy, I mean the Windows Explorer open and close animations are slow. Moving a window around is slow. Typing and clicking are slower than usual, but the mouse movement is fine. Trying to run a game where I normally get 30-40 fps in drops down to 1 fps and doesn't even make it to the title screen.

I have run multiple **anti-malware** scans from various programs, from Malwarebytes to TDSSKiller. Found nothing.

I have unchecked needless startup processes in **msconfig**. No results.

There were **no recent changes**, installations, or updates.

**Check Disk**, **System File Check**, and **Windows Memory Diagnostic** found no issues.

The CPU, RAM, I/O, and graphics usage percentages are all normal. No overheating.

**Safe Mode runs normally**, but I don't know if that's because the cause isn't happening or if Safe Mode is much lighter on resources.

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit SP1
- 3.4 GHz Intel Core i7 processor
- 8 GB RAM
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 550 Ti graphics card
- 128 GB SSD, 100% healthy according to Hard Disk Sentinel

What could possibly be happening, and what can I do to fix this?

---

Note: I bolded key words for TL;DR and quick glance purposes.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but my Nvidia drivers have been doing this to me. Restarting the "Nvidia LocalSystem Container" fixed it. Although I have to do this nearly after every reboot.

Comment: It turned out to be the NVU service--or "NVIDIA driver updater"... I contacted Nvidia about it. Leaving it disabled fixes my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a service called NVU. Its description claims it to be the "NVIDIA driver updater". The file itself is "C:\Windows\nvidia\wintask.exe". I emailed Nvidia about it, and it does not belong to them.

It turns out the sister program, NvUpdater64.exe, is a virtual currency miner. Both of these files are located in C:\Windows\nvidia.

I have submitted them to a few anti-malware companies.

Comment: A very late follow up to this, but also having similar issues.  How did you discover that it was the NVU causing probelms?  IMy pc is crazy laggy today and have done the same things as you.  Just wondering how you zoned in on this

Comment: I am sorry, but it was much too long ago for me to remember how I found it. I think the other commenter's post had me looking at all the Nvidia stuff, and I may have found it in the Task Manager. The suspicious part was how "NVIDIA driver updater" was "wintask.txt". The crazy part is that it managed to hide itself from the Resource Monitor while bogging down the system. I still have no idea how that is possible.

Comment: No worries.  Thanks for the reply.  Mine was awful for most of a day.  Didn't know what to do.  Shut it down, took it to the shop and the 15 minute drive was enough for it to start working perfectly again...  No idea what has happened there